# How can I pass global Meteor variables to templates and access and use them?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making a small, SPA game that simulates the stock market. There are lots of variables that affect prices and behaviours, but ultimately the core is a limited set of variables that apply to everything that the game works from. That's why I want to store these values globally.

So, I can't work out how to bring these globals into the template so that I can use them. I've shown the hacky way I'm doing it below which works but it's deprecated. I've read the documentation and can't find where it makes clear how to properly do this. Here's what I've got:

**client/accounts.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.bankAccounts.BANK_ACCOUNTS = function(){
    return BANK_ACCOUNTS;
  }

}
```

**client/rogue.html** (This is the base HTML page)

```
<head>
  <title>rogue</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Rogue</h1>
  {{ > bankAccounts }}
</body>

<template name="bankAccounts">
  <p>Trading Account: {{ BANK_ACCOUNTS.trading }}</p>
  <p>Loan Account: {{ BANK_ACCOUNTS.offshore }}</p>
  <p>Offshore Account: {{ BANK_ACCOUNTS.loan }}</p>
  <p>Total Holdings: {{ BANK_ACCOUNTS.holdingsValue }}</p>
  <p>Net Worth: {{ BANK_ACCOUNTS.netWorth }}</p>
  <button>Sleep</button>
</template>
```

**lib/globals.js**

```
BANK_ACCOUNTS = {
    trading: 100,
    offshore: 200,
    loan: 300,
    holdingsValue: 4000,
    netWorth: 0
}
```

Also, once they're loaded in correctly, what's the syntax to access them when using a button click event? Any help appreciated!

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Are you wanting a set of global variables that are used in multiple templates, can change, are specific to each user, and don't need to be persisted?  If not, correct what's wrong in my comment and I'll give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a global helper to go with your global variable:

```
Template.registerHelper('BANK_ACCOUNTS',function(){
  return BANK_ACCOUNTS;
});
```

Then you can use `{{BANK_ACCOUNTS.key}}` in any template.

Comment: Hi Michel, thanks for this! Is there a file where this is best to live, structurally?

Comment: Just put it in `/client`

Comment: You are the don. Worked well. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Michel, do you know what the syntax would be to use these variables in the context of button click event?

Comment: `BANK_ACCOUNTS` is just a javascript global, you can use it in an event handler just like any other global variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a rational and non messy structure for your app's globals, I highly recommend reading the following article:

https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/

I guess that is what you are looking for.